# Creating custom windows border edge disapears when resize smaller

Tags: c++, winapi

Pretty much what the title says.

Im trying to make my own border, like that of visual studio 2015.
Once i have the border working like it should i will add a child window that is the main window for my program, the border will be the parent.
Will also try and add a outer glow once i get it working.

But the problem im having right now is, When i drag my border to resize it to make it smaller, The right or bottom start to get thinner depending on how fast i drag the mouse.

Is there a better way to do this or is there a simple step i can take to fix it.

```
#include <windows.h>

LPTSTR className_ = TEXT("BorderWindow");

BOOL WINAPI Init(HINSTANCE hInstance, INT cmdShow);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);


INT WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow) {
    MSG msg;
    if (!Init(hInstance, nCmdShow)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (INT)msg.wParam;
}


BOOL WINAPI Init(HINSTANCE hInstance, INT cmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex{ 0 };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = 0;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = className_;
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hwnd_ = CreateWindow(className_, className_, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 200, 500, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hwnd_)
        return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(hwnd_, cmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd_);

    return TRUE;
}


void CreateHole(HWND hWnd)
{
    HRGN WindowRgn;
    HRGN HoleRgn;

    //Get the window region:
    RECT windowrect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &windowrect);

    int width = windowrect.right - windowrect.left;
    int height = windowrect.bottom - windowrect.top;
    WindowRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, width, height);

    //Create the hole region:
    HoleRgn = CreateRectRgn(2, 2, width - 2, height - 2);

    CombineRgn(WindowRgn, WindowRgn, HoleRgn, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(hWnd, WindowRgn, TRUE);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:
        CreateHole(hwnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        // remove default borders
        return 0;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        POINT pt = { LOWORD(lparam), HIWORD(lparam) };
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

        if (pt.y > (rc.bottom - 5))
        {
            if (pt.x > (rc.right - 5))
            {
                return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
            }
        }

        return HTBORDER;
    }

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Comment: Can we see a [mcve] instead of your partial `BorderWindow` implementation? Removing any abstractions is highly recommended.

Comment: @IInspectable i updated the code, it is complete, you should be able to build it.

Comment: `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` are not the right way to retrieve mouse pointer coordinates packed into an `LPARAM`. Use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` instead.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue using OPs code. Not really sure why that happens but AFAIK window regions don't play well with DWM. Do you need irregular shape of frame or is rectangle sufficient?

Comment: @zett42 i just need a rectangle border to wrap around its child windows

Answer (score 0):

If you only need rectangular frame, an easier solution can be achieved as follows:

- Window style should be such that normally the whole frame would be shown (`WS_CAPTION|WS_POPUP` works well for me).
- Call `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` with `MARGINS{0,0,0,1}`.
- Call `SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_FRAMECHANGED)` to recalculate NC area.
- Return 0 from `WM_NCCALCSIZE` if wParam is `TRUE`. This has the effect of extending the client area to the window size including frame. The regular window frame will be removed, but shadow will still be drawn by DWM (see also remarks section of [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx)).
- In `WM_PAINT` draw your frame and content area as you like but make sure to set opaque alpha channel for the margin defined by the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` call. Otherwise part of regular frame would be visible in this area. You may use GDI+ for that as most regular GDI functions ignore alpha channel.

You can put child controls into this window, just as normal. Just make sure child controls don't overlap the margin defined by the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` call because most GDI controls ignore the alpha channel.

Comment: Wouldnt the drawn border/frame in WM_Paint disappear on the edge im resizing window from?

Comment: @vusuzireru Call `InvalidateRgn()` in `WM_SIZE` to add frame to the update region. If frame drawing still lags too much, replace the call with `RedrawWindow()`. Make sure to check update region in `WM_PAINT` to draw only the necessary parts. Though there will always be a little lagging when resizing the window, which can be noted even with regular windows. You can't do much about that.